# How to call a function after a variable assignment completes in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, state

Similar to other questions not not quite the same: I have a variable assignment which involves calling a function that takes a significant amount of time to run, and I want to trigger a function after that assignment finishes. (The function I want to trigger is a React setState function, if relevant).

The line of code currently looks something like this:

```
const data = handler.get(endpoint).then(res => setMyState("finished getting endpoint"))
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be assigning the result of the ".then()" segment to "data" instead of the "handler.get" segment.

Is there a way I can trigger a '.then()' off of a variable assignment while capturing the value of the left half of the function chain?

Comment: The only assignment happening here is a `Promise` assigned to `data`. You're never using the resolved value from `handler.get()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a useEffect hook with the variable you assign as a dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
  // check if 'data' isn't empty
  setMyState("finished getting endpoint");
}, [data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [Promise.prototype.finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally). This will run after the promise resolves or rejects but it will not effect the resolved value.

```js
// mocks
const handler={get:()=>new Promise((r)=>{setTimeout(r,200,"handler resolved value");})};
const setMyState=(v)=>{console.log("[setMyState]",v);};
const endpoint = "https://example.com/";

const dataPromise = handler.get(endpoint)
  .finally(() => {
    setMyState("finished getting endpoint");
  });
  
// you can still reference the resolved value
dataPromise.then((res) => {
  console.log("[dataPromise]", res);
});
```

---

A simpler option is to use `async` / `await` syntax instead

```ts
const getData = async () => {
  const data = await handler.get(endpoint);
  setMyState("finished getting endpoint");
  return data;
};
```